# Smear of widget when using CustomPainter

Tags: flutter

I am having an issue when i try to use a custom Widget that uses CustomPainter() to draw shapes that go inside a ListView.builder().

The issue that i am running into is when i scroll through the list containing these widget they seem to "smear" the area they paint in....

Its best to look at these picture:
These is the ListView before scrolling... 
[image: Before Scrolling]
These is after i scroll to the left a little.
[image: After Scrolling]
This is after i scroll all the way to the left.
[image: After Full scroll]

As you can see the widget seems to smear itself as the listview is scrolled??

I am think that the listview needs to be repainted when the items are scrolled...
I tried changing the shouldRepaint() method from false to true with no effect...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: TextOnCanvasList(),
    );
  }
}

class TextOnCanvasList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> listOfNames = ["Matt","John","Bill","Doug","Paul","Hanz","Ruby","Karl"];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        reverse: false,
        itemBuilder: (_, int index) => TextOnCanvasWidget(this.listOfNames[index]),
        itemCount: listOfNames.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TextOnCanvasWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String  name;
  TextOnCanvasWidget(this.name);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new CustomPaint(
          size: Size(65, 20),
          foregroundPainter: new TextOnCanvasPainter(this.name),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class TextOnCanvasPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final String name;
  TextOnCanvasPainter(this.name);
  static const l0 = 50.0;
  static final l1 = 10.0;
  static final h = 30.0;
  final Path chevron = new Path()
    ..relativeLineTo(l0, 0)
    ..relativeLineTo(0, h )
    ..relativeLineTo(-l0, 0)
    ..relativeLineTo(0, -h )
    ..close();
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint fillShape = new Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0;
    TextSpan span = new TextSpan(
      style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.red[600]),
      text: this.name,
    );
    TextPainter tp = new TextPainter(
        text: span,
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
    tp.layout(minWidth: 500.0);
    canvas.drawPath(chevron, fillShape);
    tp.paint(canvas, new Offset(l1, h / 8));
    canvas.save();
    canvas.restore();
  }
  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(TextOnCanvasPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just tried didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: i run your original code and it works just fine: when scrolling you can see blue rectangles separated by background

Comment: ... huh.. Looks like it was an issue with my emulator... i tried on another emulator and it worked as expected..